Слой в файле .ui в Qt

Внутри QTabWidget у меня расположены три QWidget, у каждого QWidget есть свой QTableWidget
У самих QWidget есть слева иконка, не могу понять что это. Это автоматически встраиваемый слой? Как задать такой же слой для tab_3

Это компоновщик (layout). ПКМ -> Компоновка -> Скомпоновать по вертикали

Спасибо, нашел)
Проблема в том, что не могу нажать, т.к. недоступно, то есть кликнул пкм-> компоновка
Но нажатие скомпоновать по горизонтали / вертикали недоступно

Если внутри нет элементов скомпоновать нельзя. Можно добавить элемент, скомпоновать, удалить.

Спасибо большое!

По итогу сработал следующий способ:


Сначала поменял компоновщик у всего виджета (centralWidget) с вертикального на горизонтальный;


После 1 шага компоновка конкретно третьей таблицы стала доступна и я смог выбрать вертикальный компоновщик;


Снова вернул вертикальный компоновщик всему виджету (centralWidget)


